# Creating iOS & Android app from a simple html5 + javascript game?

Tags: android, ios, html, mobile

I've written some simple online games using purely HTML5 and JavaScript. Nothing fancy, no server side stuff involved, essentially each game is just a single .html (which includes javascript and css) and some .png and .jpg images.

Now, this kinda works on mobile devices as well (android/iphone/ipad) by just surfing to the particular page, but I guess a dedicated app would work better / be more convenient on these devices.

I have exactly *zero* experience developing for iOS or Android, so maybe this question is too complicated to fully answer right away, but:

**Is it possible to create an app for Android, and similarly for iOS (iphone/ipad), based on my html page, other than basically rewriting the entire game for those particular platforms?**

If yes, how do I go about this? What would be the easiest way? Is there a ton of Android / iOS knowledge required, or is there some kind of generic "conversion" that wraps my html page (+required images) into a mobile app?

Comment: Thanks guys! Both look useful, I'll start off with phonegap for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess that [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) would perfectly fit your needs.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Appcelerator can do that. It builds native Android apps and iOS. The language is based on HTML5 and JS so I think it can help you.

http://www.appcelerator.com/

Comment: phonegap is slightly better in this case because it literally loads from an html page :)

Answer (score 2):

https://cordova.apache.org

- Mobile apps with HTML, CSS & JS
- Target multiple platforms with one code base
- Free and open source

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use construct 2. It has better development tools for HTML5. Here is a link to [construct 2](https://www.scirra.com/construct2) website.